# Error occurred while switch branch in visual studio 2015 git repo, Could not rmdir Access is denied

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-update

The following error occurring while switching the git branch in Visual Studio 2015.

An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not rmdir 'Directory Path': Access is denied.
It happens when I try to switch the current branch.

The root cause of this issue is that all folders on my computer are marked read-only. And it is not removing the read-only attribute even If I remove it from the property window. This is a very known issue and so many people talked about it over the internet but no one has any solution.

I tried the following but did not work for me.

1. https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10/
2. https://bobcares.com/blog/folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10/

Update

I checked it with git bash. I was able to switch the branch. But not with visual studio.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Where do you create the directory and from which branch to which other branch are you switching? Do you get the error when committing or only after committing when switching branches?

Comment: @knittl I am not getting any error while committing the changes. Only when switching the branch.

Comment: I got the root cause of this issue. All folders on my computer are marked read-only. And it is not removing the read-only attribute even If I remove it from the property window. This is a very known issue and so many people talked about it over internet but no one has any solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things to check:

1. Your working directory is writable by your user.
2. Your repository (i.e. `.git` folder and all subfolders and files) is writable by your user.
3. Your file system is writable.
4. There is enough space left on the file system.
5. No application has a lock on the directory/file. Windows is notorious for locking files for exclusive access. Opening Git Bash in this directory could cause it and even Visual Studio might very well be the case.
6. Close Visual Studio and try the operation from outside of it, e.g. with Git Bash.
7. No case-folding which results in conflicts. To Git `Folder` and `folder` are two different paths, to Windows, they are the same.

Comment: you are correct. All folders on my pc are marked as read-only.
I have tried every solution available on the net to remove the read-only attribute but it keeps coming back. I think this problem is occurring because of the read-only attribute on folders only.


1. https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10/
2. https://bobcares.com/blog/folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10/